# nginx handle multiple locations for one server

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, php-fpm, configuration, socket

I need to setup a virtual host to run my `users.example.com` website. It needs PHP support via php-fpm.
The ideia is to have a mapping like this:

`users.example.com/~user1/folder/file.php` -> `/home/user1/www/folder/file1.php`
`users.example.com/user1/folder/file.php` -> `/home/user1/www/folder/file1.php`
`users.example.com/~user2/stuff/about.html` -> `/home/user2/www/stuff/about.html`

et cetera. Each users files run under a different PHP-FPM pool (so, a different fpm socket), for security reasons. The socket has a full path off `/var/run/{USERNAME}_fpm.sock`. How can I make this server configuration?

Initial idea is to have a `server { }`, with `server_name users.example.com;` and a `location` with a different `root` for each user. I'd like to know if that works and the setup for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this myself, but something like this could work

```
server {
    server_name users.example.com;
    listen 80;

    location ~ /(?:~)?(?<user>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ {
        alias /home/$user/www/;
        fastcgi_pass /var/run/$user_fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

So, in the location line, we capture the username to the $user variable, and then use the variable for the `alias` and `fastcgi_pass` directives. You can also expand the regular expression for the user home directory if you want to include more characters in it.

The `(?:~)?` part matches the optional `~` character in the pathname.